# 'which' doesn't find cuda after 'sudo dnf install cuda'

Tags: cuda, installation, nvidia, fedora, fedora-27

I ran `sudo dnf install cuda` on Fedora 27. The output is:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:05 ago on Thu 05 Jul 2018 10:32:51 AM CEST.
Package cuda-1:9.1.85.3-7.fc27.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

But when I do `which cuda` on the terminal, I get:

```
/usr/bin/which: no cuda in (/home/username/anaconda3/bin:/home/username/anaconda2/bin:/home/username/anaconda3/bin:/home/username/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/username/.local/bin:/home/username/bin)
```

Do I have cuda installed ?

**Linux distribution** : 
x86_64
Fedora release 27 (Twenty Seven)

**GPU available** (output of `lspci | grep -i nvidia`): 
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)

Answer (score 1):

There is no executable called 'cuda'. The libraries get installed someplace like /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.

You can try to run 'nvcc --version' but you can't be sure until you're able to run a cuda based application.

More details here:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#verify-installation

Comment: "There is no executable called 'cuda'", what is cuda then ?

Comment: @dada if you have to ask that, you really have no business asking CUDA questions on [SO]